# Popup on Sharepoint. How to add?

Tags: development

I have got a question, How to add popap window to Sharepoint by the code. I tried many thinks, but they could be block by web browsers. I must find that want unblock by web browsers.

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grzegorz,

This is a simplest form of SharePoint 2010 Modal Dialog, using SP.Dialog class!

```
function test() { 
        //debugger; 
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ 
            url: "/Lists/Announcements/NewForm.aspx", 
            title: "Add item", 
            allowMaximize: true, 
            showClose: true, 
            width: 800, 
            height: 600, 
           dialogReturnValueCallback: silentCallback 
       }); 
   }; 

   function silentCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
   } 

   function refreshCallback(dialogResult, returnValue) { 
       SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK); 
   }
```

This is same dialog which opens when you add new item to a list, or edit any item! You can provide any url in SP Dialog Options!

[More reading here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx)

**Edited:**

Try this:

```
LiteralControl controlLit = new LiteralControl();
controlLit.Text = "<a onclick='javascript:test();' href='#'>click here</a>";
 e.Cell.Controls.Add(controlLit);
```

Comment: And we do it in .cs files ?

**Thank You very much Arsalan Adam Khatri**

Comment: And how to add SP. Its gets me in red.

Comment: It is Javascript, you don't have this option in .cs file.. You can write this in a Visual Web Part or a Content Editor Web Part, and call test() function on a button click or anywhere!

Comment: so in <script></script> I want to after render on calendar, when a Percent are more then 8/8

Comment: you can inject the <script> in Content Editor Web Part, and then call the function by making <a onclick="javascript:test();" href="#">click here to open popup<\a>

Comment: Yes I know, but i must on render. When I get more then 8/8 then Dialog modal Should popup

Comment: If This:
 `if (sumaProcentow > 8)
                    {
                        e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#FF0000");
                        e.Cell.CssClass = "dni_swiateczne";
}` Modal should popup

Comment: Yes, here you can add a new Literal Control and set popup as mentioned above!

Comment: nt only after link click, but after if happened.

Comment: Ah Okey :) :) :)

Comment: I added `e.Cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(("<a onclick='javascript:test();' href='#'>")));` But control doesn't show.

Comment: updated the answer for you!

Comment: Now it's work, but i mast click on link , and I want to autostart popup

Comment: With no click, only start when sumaProcentow > 8

Comment: Post another question for this :D, I will give the answer there!

Comment: The topic is ready :)